# Eosflare.io shows the wrong Connector Balance for EOSIO.RAM account?

Tags: smart-contract, ram, bancor

It currently shows 66730 EOS (http://eosflare.io/account/eosio.ram), but here in the first answer ([How to get current (last) RAM price?](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/847/how-to-get-current-last-ram-price)) is said that it should be 1021789.6640 EOS (see quote.balance). These two numbers differ too much. Why?