# How to calculate EOSIO ram price?

Tags: ram, eosio.system, ram-allocation

Hello i want to know how we can calculate eosio ram price is there any rpc call available or any libraray like eosjs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get current (last) RAM price?](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/847/how-to-get-current-last-ram-price)

Answer (score 0):

this question has been asked before several times, one instance is here: [How to get current (last) RAM price?](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/847/how-to-get-current-last-ram-price)

also check this telegram group history and you will find threads about this topic there too: https://t.me/joinchat/0uhWYfXVpPlkNTA1